# How to design class hierarchy?

Tags: java, class

I'm programming in `Java 7` and now I need to create a base class `BaseCondition` for all concrete Conditions. What do I mean is that I have some types: `Date`, `Integer`, and some `enum`s and I need to store conditions like `_ALL_INTEGERS > 100 and < 200`, `_ALL_INTEGERS > 100`, `_ALL_INTEGERS < 200` and so for Dates (more, less, between). For `enum`s I'm going to chose only one value now, so If

```
enum BonusType{
    BIRTHDAY,
    REGISTRATION
}
```

then the conditions will look like `BonusType= BIRTHDAY` and `BonusType= REGISTRATION`.

So what I was trying to write was

```
public class <T> ConditionBase{
    private T low;
    private T high;
    //GET, SET
}
```

and used `low=high` when I would need to create a condition for enum. All conditions would be a derived class as follows:

```
public class DateCondition extends BaseCondition<Date>{ }
public class BonusTypeCondition extends BaseCondition<BonusType>{ }
```

Example of a concrete condition:

```
BaseCondition c = new BonusTypeCondition();
c.setLow(BonusType.BIRTHDAY);
c.setHigh(BonusType.BIRTHDAY);
```

***QUESTION***: I'm not sure about if won't get into troubles when I try to extend some functionality (adding more complicated conditions). Couldn't you suggest something more scalable?

Comment: It seems that you're reinventing [Predicate](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/Predicate.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, your concept is very close to storing a Java 8 Lambda/closure on each case. If you can't switch versions, you have to abstract the fact that `low` or 'high` might not be reasonable for Enums. So your true base for condition should be like this:

```
public interface ConditionBase<T>
{
   boolean fulfills(T object);  // True if this object fullfills the condition.
}
```

That is the only general case. You can then create some implementations for classes with upper bounds.

```
public class<T extends Comparable> LessThanX() implements ConditionBase<T>
{
   ...
   private T value;

   ...
   public boolean fullfills(T object)
   {
      return object.compareTo(value) < 0;
   }
}
```

Forgive me if there are any syntax errors there, my Java is rusty since I moved to Scala.

You can define as many type of conditions as you want, with one or more internal values (between for isntance). You can also create some wrappers that contain several conditions inside them and check the object against all of them, etc.

Comment: Interesting approach, I'll take it. But what's not quite clear to me is how I'm supposed to implement a condition for interval (DATE BETWEE '2011-11-11' and '2012-12-12')?

Comment: Well, same as LessTanX you can build BetweenXY, which constructor receives X and Y, the type must be comparable, and the fullfills method checks the whole condition. Alternatively, you could create a CompoundAndCondition with an internal list of BaseConditions and append a LessThanX and a MoreThanX conditions to it. Check the last paragraph...